# Scrapy project error: "undefined variable" when actually I have defined this variable

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm following this tutorial https://www.practicalecommerce.com/Monitor-Competitor-Prices-with-Python-and-Scrapy exactly how is said, step-by-step, but when I get to the part where I run the spider with the command:

> scrapy crawl massEffect -o results.csv

it shows this mistake:

> NameError: global name 'TfawItem' is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my items.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

import scrapy


class TfawItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    upc = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
```

my massEffect.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class MasseffectSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'massEffect'
    allowed_domains = ['tfaw.com']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.tfaw.com/Companies/Dark-Horse/Series?series_name=Mass+Effect',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css('div a.boldlink::attr(href)'):
            url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_detail_page)

    def parse_detail_page(self, response):
        comic = TfawItem()
        comic['title'] = response.css('div.iconistan + b span.blackheader::text').extract()
        comic['price'] = response.css('span.blackheader ~ span.redheader::text').re('[$]\d+\.\d+')
        comic['upc'] = response.xpath('/html/body/table[1]/tr/td[4]/table[3]/tr/td/table/tr/td[contains(., "UPC:")]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()').extract()
        comic['url'] = response.url
        yield comic
```

And the hierarchy of my project:

```
tfaw/

    scrapy.cfg

    results.csv

    tfaw/

        __init__.py

        __init__.pyc

        items.py

        middlewares.py

        pipelines.py

        settings.py

        settings.pyc

        spiders/

            __init__.py

            __init__.pyc

            massEffect.py

            massEffect.pyc
```

Comment: Classes and other names from other files (aka modules) must be `import`ed explicitly in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't import `TfawItem` anywhere in `massEffect.py`.

Add for example `from ..items import TfawItem` to the top of `massEffect.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not importing `TfawItem` into your `massEffect.py` file. Depending on your python version you can do either:

```
from ..items import TfawItem
```

or

```
from modulename.items import TfawItem
```

Comment: Almost, it worked when I put two dots before 'items', but thanks anyway for the answer :D